# How to store the contents of the file to a variable in ansible when the file contains new lines as well

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to store content of the certificate.pem file to a variable using the following task:

```
 - name: Get the contents of the root certificate
   shell: cat {{ ca_certificate_file }}

 - name: Decode data and store as fact
   set_fact:
     root_certificate_content: "{{ ca_certificate_data.stdout }}"
```

The variable root_certificate_content has the entire content of the file but instead of a new line it is replacing it with a space. I there a way I can get the certificate content as it is in the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**

Q: ***"A new line is replacing with a space."***

A: What you see depends on the [callback](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html). Given the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/certificate.pem 
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Get the content of the file either by *lookup* (if the file is on the controller)

```yaml
  ca_certificate_file: /tmp/certificate.pem
  cert: "{{ lookup('file', ca_certificate_file) }}"
```

, or declare the variables

```yaml
  ca_certificate_file: /tmp/certificate.pem
  cert: "{{ out.stdout }}"
```

and read the file on the remote host (works on the controller too)

```yaml
    - command: "cat {{ ca_certificate_file }}"
      register: out
```

Display the variable *cert*

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: cert
```

The default callback format is JSON (the newlines \n are visible)

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=default ansible-playbook pb.yml -l localhost
 ...
ok: [localhost] => {
    "cert": "line 1\nline 2\nline 3"
}
```

The YAML format would be

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml ansible-playbook pb.yml -l localhost
  ...
ok: [localhost] => 
  cert: |-
    line 1
    line 2
    line 3
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  vars:

    ca_certificate_file: /tmp/certificate.pem
    # cert: "{{ lookup('file', ca_certificate_file }}"
    cert: "{{ out.stdout }}"

  tasks:

    - command: "cat {{ ca_certificate_file }}"
      register: out

    - debug:
        var: cert
```

---

**origin**

Try [lookup plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#using-lookup-plugins)

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        root_certificate_content: "{{ lookup('file', ca_certificate_file) }}"
```

For example, " `the variable "root_certificate_content" should have the contents of the file as it is. If the file has a new line then it should come as the new line`".  The play below

```yaml
    - hosts: localhost
      tasks:
        - set_fact:
            root_certificate_content: "{{ lookup('file', 'cert1') }}"
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ root_certificate_content.split('\n') }}"
```

with the file (3 lines with newline each)

```
shell> cat cert1 
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

gives the content of the variable *root_certificate_content* (3 lines with newline each)

```yaml
  "msg": [
      "line 1", 
      "line 2", 
      "line 3"
  ]
```

"`if you just show the value of root_certificate_content without using .split('\n') in the debug msg`"

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: root_certificate_content
```

then the newlines can be seen in the string

```yaml
  "root_certificate_content": "line 1\nline 2\nline 3"
```

Comment: lookup also didn't solve the problem of new line and spaces. I'm still getting spaces instead of new lines

Comment: This is strange. It works for me. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I want that the variable "root_certificate_content" should have the contents of the file as it is means if the file has new line then it should come as new line not a space.

Comment: Exactly. That's what I see in the answer. I've updated it with more details.

Comment: what if you just echo the value of root_certificate_content without using .split('\n') in the debug msg