# How to write a file's content in variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have written Ansible code where I am generating keys. The Script generates a private key file.

```yaml
- name: Generating Public and Private Key
  local_action:
    module: command
    cmd: './Auth-PUB-PVT-keytool.sh -privK {{OUTPUT_FOLDER}}/keys/{{PVT_KEY_NAME}}.key'
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{HOST_USER}}"
  # run_once: True
  no_log: "false"
```

Now I want to write the key data into an Ansible variable. For example: I have the file `test.key` with below content

```
jsbciusgdcxjasbciuygwndichsiuzgxciukjsdgniugziuduwyfmygxynYUXGNiusgzbuxtsaiuxdniufgdbyxfaiysrbcuyiacfxuyibstycfbxuybuyxtduyntzicytnyudn
```

Now I want that in my Ansible variable "MY_KEY_VALUE" the content of key file will be assigned i.e.

```
MY_KEY_VALUE: "jsbciusgdcxjasbciuygwndichsiuzgxciukjsdgniugziuduwyfmygxynYUXGNiusgzbuxtsaiuxdniufgdbyxfaiysrbcuyiacfxuyibstycfbxuybuyxtduyntzicytnyudn"
```

How to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the file on the controller or on the nodes?

Comment: The file is on the node. You can say I am running it on localhost. No remote server.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε please find the above info

Comment: "_I have written a Ansible code where I am generating keys._", can you show us the code? Since according "_Now I want to write the keys data to an Ansible variable. For example: I have the file `test.key` with below content_" you generated the key in Ansible already and wrote it into a file, so wasn't in a variable before? Can you show us the part where the file was generated?

Comment: @U880D here is the code.
```
  local_action:
    module: command
    cmd: './Auth-PUB-PVT-keytool.sh -privK {{OUTPUT_FOLDER}}/keys/{{PVT_KEY_NAME}}.ppk -pubK'
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{HOST_USER}}"
  # run_once: True
  no_log: "false"
```
The Script generates a private key file. Now I want the content of that file in a Ansible variable.

Comment: This question looks (now) like a duplicate of [Ansible: Set variable to file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003880/).

Comment: => `your_var: "{{ lookup('file', OUTPUT_FOLDER ~ '/keys/' ~PVT_KEY_NAME ~ '.key') }}"` See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_lookup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best approach for files on the Control Node would be [using lookup plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#using-lookup-plugins). See [Ansible: Set variable to file content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24014549/6771046) or [How to store the contents of the file to a variable in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56931324/6771046).

---

Another approach can be be to use the [`slurp` module – Slurps a file from remote nodes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html).

For a file

```bash
~/test$ cat test.key
VALUE
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Slurp var from file
    # delegate_to: localhost # if necessary
    slurp:
      src: test.key
    register: MY_KEY

  - name: Show var
    debug:
      msg: "{{ MY_KEY['content'] | b64decode }}"
```

results into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Slurp var from file] ******
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show var] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: VALUE
```

---

If the data structure of your file `test.key` is already YAML, you could just read it in via [`include_vars` module – Load variables from files, dynamically within a task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html).

For a file

```bash
~/test$ cat test.key
MY_KEY: "VALUE"
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Read var file
    # delegate_to: localhost # if necessary
    include_vars:
      file: test.key
      name: stuff

  - name: Show var
    debug:
      var: stuff
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Read var file] ******
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show var] ***********
ok: [localhost] =>
  stuff:
    MY_KEY: VALUE
```